# How do I set permissions using SSHFS Manager on Windows 7?

Tags: linux, windows-7, ssh, debian, sshfs

I'm trying to edit files on a Linux server using my local text editor (Sublime or PyCharm).

When I try to save I get the error "Unable to save:......."

I think this is a permissions issue.

How do I set permissions using SSHFS Manager on Windows 7?